# Handling stripe with reactJs

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I'm trying to handle credit card payments using stripe and reactjs. I'm following the tutorial here https://github.com/stripe-archive/react-stripe-elements. See the get started section. The only problem I have is that I need to submit the credit card form on the component page where the  code is (the first page that is created) and not the CheckoutForm page. How do I do that?

I tried doing the following

```
 var elements = useElements();
 const card = elements.getElement(CardElement);
 const result = await stripePromise.createToken(card);
 if (result.error) {
    console.dir(result.error.message);
 } else {
    console.dir(result.token);
 }
```

but I'm not able to use a hook function useElements in a class compomnent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the library you've linked to is [deprecated](https://github.com/stripe-archive/react-stripe-elements#weve-moved-to-stripereact-stripe-js), the new version is [this one](https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-js). Since you're using the hooks you must be using the new library already, though.

If you're using Class components, the documentation provides an example of an [alternate integration pattern](https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-js#using-class-components) using the `<Elements>` provider and `<ElementsConsumer>` explicitly.